# Regex to not allow '.', '_', '-' at String Start or End and should not have consecutive '.' and the rest all special characters should not be allowed

Tags: javascript, regex, string, validation

the output should be like

```
.test_test1-test - INVALID
test2_test-test. - INVALID
_test.test-test- - INVALID
test.test-test - VALID
test._test-test - INVALID
```

The current expression that i have is mentioned below

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9](?![_.-]?[^\na-zA-Z0-9]{2}).*?[a-zA-Z0-9]$/gim
```

Comment: Can you also include your current code?  Stack Overflow tries to not be a free coding service.

Comment: This is the code that i have currently.
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9](?![_.-]?[^\na-zA-Z0-9]{2}).*?[a-zA-Z0-9]$/gim

Comment: Difficult to understand your requirements. Something like [`/^[a-z\d]+(?:[_.-][a-z\d]+)*$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/SGzbzT/1/) maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I can come up with a regex like this:

```
^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*(?:\.[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)+$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yl6Qms/2)**

[image]

However, this will generate a lot of backtracking and it will be slow if strings are long

I think the best solution for you is to split the string by `.` and then validate that each string matches the pattern of `^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$`

Comment: Hi, how do you create this awesome diagram of your regex ?

Comment: @Nicolas there are some online tools for them. The one I created is provided by debuggex.com

Answer (score 1):

Your regex seams to be a little bit complicated for what you are trying to do.
 You have two part to your regex:

- The first one is the `test` plus a symbole, that repeat twice.
- The second one is the `test` but no symbol, that end the regex.

Also, you don't need to validate `A-Z` in your match group since your regex has an case insencitive flag.
Here is a working example :

```
/^([a-z0-9]+[._-]?){2}([a-z0-9]+)$/gmi
```

You can test more cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/DEtMFQ/2)

Comment: Silly comment... you can use `[._-]?` instead of `[._-]{0,1}` if you want to shorten it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
^[^a-z0-9]|[_.-]{2,}|[^a-z0-9]$
```

and then negate the result:

```
rg = new RegExp('^[^a-z0-9]|[_.-]{2,}|[^a-z0-9]$','gim')
!rg.test('test.test-test')
```

Examples:

```js
rg = new RegExp('^[^a-z0-9]|[_.-]{2,}|[^a-z0-9]$','gim')

console.log('Valid')
console.log('test.test-test', !rg.test('test.test-test'))

console.log('Invalid')
console.log('.test.test-test', !rg.test('.test.test-test'))
```

More examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/vvK5CD/1)

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions are applied to the entire string first, it ends up like this :

`/^(?![._-])(?!.*[._-]$)(?!.*[._-][._-])[\w.-]*$/`

https://regex101.com/r/hnVimE/1

Explained

```
 ^                         # BOS
 (?! [._-] )               # Not . or _ or - at beginning
 (?! .* [._-] $ )          # Not . or _ or - at end
 (?! .* [._-] [._-] )      # No consecutive  . or _ or - 
 [\w.-]*                   # Not special characters, except  . or _ or -
 $                         # EOS
```

This is set to match the empty string `[\w.-]*`, set the quantifier to `+`
if text is a requirement also.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?!.*\.\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_-](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z0-9_-])?$/
```

This expression worked with all the scenarios mentioned.